# Where should link between Azure Function and Azure Keyvault be configured?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I developing an Azure Function running Python for the first time to some of you, so please bear with me. So this question might be trivial. I'm deploying my function using a standard build and deploy pipeline in Azure Devops. For now only to test. The function uses some information that is sensitive like API keys, passwords, etc. Those secrets are stored in an Azure KeyVault. As of now I can deploy it successfully.

I've created a service principal for my Azure Function, and both the Keyvault and the Function are in the same ressourcegroup.

In my script I'm calling the secrets using the os.environ method i.e.:

```
api_key = os.environ['api_key']
```

It works well when I'm developing using the local_settings.json file in Visual Studio Code.

My question is now; should I configure the enviroment variables in the Azure Function or in Azure DevOps i.e. should I link to the secrets in the keyvault from the Azure Function or in Azure Devops?
If I'm setting up the link to the secrets in Azure Function, do I still need to use @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=) when setting it up in Azure Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should I link to the secrets in the keyvault from the Azure Function or in Azure Devops

In the Azure Function. Otherwise, the secrets are exposed in the AppSettings of the Function app.

> If I'm setting up the link to the secrets in Azure Function, do I still need to use @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=) when setting it up in Azure Function

Yes. See the [docs](https://If%20I%27m%20setting%20up%20the%20link%20to%20the%20secrets%20in%20Azure%20Function,%20do%20I%20still%20need%20to%20use%20@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=)%20when%20setting%20it%20up%20in%20Azure%20Function) for the KeyVault references.

Comment: Thanks, Silent. I'll try to implement this and get back!

Answer (score 0):

You should create variable for keyvaulturl, clientId, and clientsecret in your azure devops release pipeline. Once you deploy the azure function from release pipeline using azure functions task you also need to set the configuration for your azure function app in that particular task.
Or using Azure app service setting task.
Now in your azure function code in the startup you need to create the connection for keyvault using env variable (keyvaulturl, clientid, client secret) and fetch all your application secrets and set it as env variable again for further use.

So you don't need to set anything in your appsettings file or in code repository.
Hope this helps